# Проблема с парсингом сайта cприменением JSOUP

Tags: android, jsoup, парсер

При парсинге сайта с помощью JSOUP происходит какой-то затуп. Вот куски кода:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
```

...

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

...

```
  for(Element table :  doc.select("div[class=roster-view]")) {

                    for (Element item : table.select("div[class=roster-view_itemContent]")) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        for (Element item_fio : item.select("div[class=roster-view_fio]")) {

                            map.put("fio", item_fio.text());
                        }
                        for (Element item_info : item.select("div[class=roster-view_info]")) {
                            map.put("info", item_info.text());
                        }
                        for (Element item_photo : item.select("div[class=roster-view_photo]")) {
                            Elements imgSrc = item_photo.select("img[src]");
                            String imgSrcStr1 = imgSrc.attr("src");
                            String imgSrcStr = "http:" + imgSrcStr1;
                          //  System.out.println(imgSrcStr);
                            map.put("photo", imgSrcStr);
                        }

     for (Element item_link : item.select("div[class=roster-view_fio]")) {
                                  Elements url_href = item_link.select("a[href]");
                                  String url1 = url_href.attr("href");
                                   String link = "http://laf.amfoot.ru" + url1;
                                   map.put("link", item_link.text());
                                 //  System.out.println(link);
                            }

                            arraylist.add(map);
                           // System.out.println(arraylist);
```

Если выводим  `System.out.println(link);`, то в консоле правильное значение, то что нужно, но вот уже после `arraylist.add(map);`, в консоль уже выводится значение `"fio"` вместо `"link"`. В чём же косяк?

Comment: "fio" вы же тоже записываете в `map` первом цикле. Опишите подробнее что вы ожидаете получить и что получаете сейчас, в чём именно проблема. А то пока не очень понятно.

Comment: @eugeneek ,в итоге необходимо получить 3 строки { fio, info, link } и картинку. А получается {fio, info, fio} и картинка. Не могу понять, почему вместо link в массиве arraylist сидит fio, ведь до добавления map в arraylist, link содержит то, что надо и если вывести на консоль, это видно.

Comment: Похоже вы запутались. "почему вместо link в массиве arraylist сидит fio" в этом предложении нет смысла. Ваш `arraylist` это лист с хеш мапами. "fio" и "link" это ключи в мапе. Видимо вы не то выводите в консоль. Значения  "{ fio, info, link } и картинка" хранятся в `map`. А набор этих мапов в `arraylist`.

Comment: @eugeneek Понятно, что значения { fio, info, link } хранятся в `map`, а он в `arrayllist`. Дело в том, что если выводить отдельно, что хранится за ключом `"link"`, то в консоле, то что надо(нужный url). Но, если выводить `arraylist` в консоль целиком, тo выводится что-то типа {fio: фио1, info: инфо1, link: фио1}. Вопрос в том, как значения из ключа `"fio" `попали под ключ `"link"` после того как их `map` положили в `arraylist`?

Comment: Вот сразу бы так написали. Проблема в том, что вы распечатываете значение `link`, а в мап кладёте текст этого линка `item_link.text()`, в котором видимо то самое фио.

Comment: @eugeneek В точку! Делал по примеру и как оказалось не совсем разобрался с моментом парсинга.